# change multiple filenames - python script

Tags: python, unicode

first i am newbie in python.
i have a bulk of files (117 files), i think their names are UTF-8 .Here is one filename sample:

```
1|Ø¬Ø§ÙØ§ JAVA : ÙÙÙÙÙ Ø§ÙØ®ØµØ§Ø¦Øµ Attributes ÙÙ Ø§ÙØ¨Ø±ÙØ¬Ø©|R9Rku3z63uI.mp4
```

i want to change these filenames so i made the following python script:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os

names = "مقدمة الدورة و \n مفهوم الكائنات في البرمجة\nمفهوم الخصائص Attributes في البرمجة............" 
i = 0
for r,dirs,files in os.walk('/media/sdd3vil/SDDEvilOthers/Programming/Java/java101/'):
     files.sort()
     fa = '\n'.join(files)
     fc = fa.split('\n')
while i < 118 :
    os.rename(fc[i], names[i])
    print "%s Changed To %s" % (f3, names[i])
    i +=1
    continue
```

the "names" variable contains the names which i want to replace in the original filenames.
but i got the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "Re.py", line 20, in <module>
        os.rename(fc[i], names[i])
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

can anyone explain what is the problem is and give us a solve.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your *names* variable is just a string and not a list, so *names[i]* is just the i-th  character in it. Either you initialize it as a list or you split() it before use.

When your code doesn't behave as you want/expect, it is usually because your variables do not contain what you think, so adding a print statement just before the error tor print the variable values should be your first reflex... (or your second, because a bit of code reviewing can spot such problems)

Comment: I don't have any problem indices because i used "print" statement and i got the result i need.I only have problem with the function that changes the filenames.Although i tried to change the filename with "mv" in the terminal but i got problem because the filename in UTF-8 format changed to Binary format.I am wondering if "mv" have any relation with that function.